# Prevent data loss in batch logging

Tags: logging

We have a service that logs every request with everything required to debug it in case of a failure. The way this is done is that on each request an async functions logs the required data to our database. But as you can already see this is not using our resources in an optimal way because we log requests one by one. Because of that I wanted to do batch logging. Imagine to actually connect to our database to perform the logging we set the threshold to 50 logs in que. If there were 49 logs in que and a power outage occurs(or anything that makes us lose this object), then we just lose all of our logs! If we have 10 servers with the same situation then we lose 49*10 logs. What is the most optimal recommended way to prevent such situation. If there are foolproof libraries for .net, I would love hear about them as well! Thanks for your time.

---

After having a conversation in the comments, I noticed I might have made the question to compilacted and that's my fault sorry. The core question is 'how to make a batch logging proccess that is not affected from data loss (on power outage, db fault, connection error and so on) or im simpler terms A RELIABLE BATCH LOGGIN SCENARIO.

Comment: You either need to guarantee you have the data, or you don't. If you need it, you need to ensure it's persisted before acknowledging the request. More importantly though, libraries like Serilog are a best-effort tool which should not be relied on to this degree; if you need to record the input data as part of a process, record it in a primary store that has an appropriate level of guarantee of correct and complete storage.

Comment: @RubenBartelink we do have the data, and we cannot rely on serilog(as mentioned in their docs about batch failurs lose all data in that batch). I'm asking for a general solution and also any OTHER tools which might be handy in this process. This question is about before performing the batch request not after it.

Comment: The fact it's no longer `serilog` at least makes the question misleading. However, it ironically also dilutes it beyond the point where this is really something that's solvable on Stack Overflow either. My bottom line advice is and was that logging is supplemental to the overall functioning and traceability of an app. In general the principles of event sourcing can be relevant in this space, but tools trumpeting themselves as "for event sourcing" will not necessarily be at all helpful.

Comment: Once again: if having the inputs be traceable is fundamental to your task, there's no skirting the fact that you should write that to a persistent store as your first step. This "stashing the inputs" is not a side-task that you use a magic library for; it's fundamental to the task, and your overall data storage mechanisms should be selected with consideration for whether they are up to the job of doing that. If you are timing the overall work and declaring that you can't afford to log the inputs correctly, then I'd say the core design is simply incomplete in the first instance.

Comment: I'd compare the notion of having a cheap high perf batch logging that's completely reliable as a commodity to that of bolting on security to a system after the fact.

Comment: @RubenBartelink I might be making the question to complicated and thats my fault sorry. In simple terms, how to make a batch logging proccess that is not affected from data loss (on power outage, db fault, connection error and so on)

Comment: To my mind, there is no 'batch logging process'. There is only recording all the stuff you need as an intrinsic part of the actual work, without separating it.

Comment: @RubenBartelink why don't you think it's possible to delegate this process, and there just optimize how 'it' could be done? If you already have a logging service and you want to optimize it, YOU SHOULD NOT change how the cosumer uses it, it is something internal to the logging serivce.

Comment: While there is an Audit mode/aspect to Serilog, it's not truly bullet proof and not widely used. The bottom line is that logging is logging - a very useful and important tool that performs a function that's orthogonal to solving your problem. If you need a guarantee of persistence from something as part of solving your problem in a correct manner, then the correct thing to do is to design that in from the off. Ultimately this is a useless philosophical debate angle, but my point is that there's a reason why the thing you seek does not exist. I have little more to add unfortunately :(

Comment: The big indicator that Serilog (or any logger) is not the answer, is that the writing of logs will never block the running of the app (throw exceptions, pause execution). While it's extremely reliable, and absolutely is not carelessly dropping things, it's role is simply not to be an audit log. (I do recommend reading up on the Serilog Audit stuff, but from the way you are talking I dont think its truly the answer for you either.)